# Error in Scopus Syntax for advanced search

Tags: scopus

I want to modify a search which is already used by someone else to see similar kind of results but the syntax shows and error and I am unable to find where is the error. Can someone help me with this. The syntax I used is as follows:

TITLE-ABS-KEY (((“Time windows” OR “VRPTW”) OR (“Multitrip” OR “Multi-trip” OR
“MTVRP”) OR (“Satellite Facilities” OR “Echelon”) OR ((“Hybrid” AND “VRP”) OR (“Green”
AND “VRP”)) OR (“Time-dependent VRP” OR “Time dependent VRP” OR “TDVRP”) OR
(“Pollution routing” OR “PRP”) OR (“Electric VRP”) OR (“Capacitated VRP” OR “CVRP”)
OR (“VRP” AND (“two-dimensional” OR “three-dimensional” OR “3D loading constraints”
OR “2D loading constraints”)) OR “Truck and Trailer” OR (“Dynamic VRP” OR “DVRP”) OR
(“Simultaneous Pickups and Deliveries” OR “VRPSPD” OR “Backhauls” OR “VRPB”) OR
(“Rich VRP”) OR (“Heterogeneous Fleet” OR “Heterogeneous” OR “HFVRP”) OR (“Multi
depot” OR “Multi-depot” OR “MDVRP”) OR (“Open VRP” OR “OVRP”) OR (“Split Delivery
VRP” OR “SDVRP”) OR (“Periodic VRP” OR “PVRP”) OR (“Stochastic VRP” OR “SVRP”)
OR (“Collaborative VRP”) OR (“Consistent VRP” OR “ConVRP”) OR (“VRP with workload
balance”) OR (“site-dependent”)) AND (“Vehicle routing” AND (“Benchmark Instances” OR
“Benchmark” OR “validate” OR “validation” OR “test” OR “tested” OR “simulate” OR “simulation”
OR “case study”) AND (“Algorithm”)) AND NOT (“Waste” OR “cash” OR “hazardous”
OR “Concrete” OR “Healthcare” OR “Cold” OR “Care” OR “Location-routing” OR “Location
routing” OR “UAV” OR “Transportation of people” OR “Flying robots” OR “Bus” OR “Asset
localization” OR “Inventory routing” OR “Blood” OR “Bike” OR “Bicycle”)) AND (LIMITTO
(SRCTYPE, “j”)) AND (LIMIT-TO (DOCTYPE, “ar”)) AND (LIMIT-TO (SUBJAREA,
“COMP”) OR LIMIT-TO (SUBJAREA, “MATH”) OR LIMIT-TO (SUBJAREA, “ENGI”)
OR LIMIT-TO (SUBJAREA, “DECI”) OR LIMIT-TO (SUBJAREA, “BUSI”)) AND ((PUBYEAR

> 2009)) AND (LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “Computers And Operations Research”)
> OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “European Journal Of Operational Research”) OR LIMITTO
> (EXACTSRCTITLE, “Expert Systems With Applications”) OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE,
> “Applied Soft Computing Journal”) OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “Computers
> And Industrial Engineering”) OR LIMIT-TO(EXACTSRCTITLE, “Information Sciences”)
> OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “International Transactions In Operational Research”)
> OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “Soft Computing”) OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE,
> “Annals Of Operations Research”) OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “Journal Of The
> Operational Research Society”) OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “Transportation Research
> Part C Emerging Technologies”) OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “Transportation Science”)
> OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “Applied Mathematical Modelling”) OR LIMIT-TO
> (EXACTSRCTITLE, “Engineering Optimization”) OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “Operations
> Research”) OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “Transportation Research Part B Methodological”)
> OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “Transportation Research Part E Logistics And
> Transportation Review”) OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “Journal Of Advanced Transportation”)
> OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “Swarm And Evolutionary Computation”) OR
> LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “IEEE Transactions On Automation Science And Engineering”)
> OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “International Journal Of Advanced Manufacturing Technology”)
> OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “International Journal Of Production Economics”)
> OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “Journal Of Intelligent Manufacturing”) OR LIMIT-TO
> (EXACTSRCTITLE, “Optimization Letters”) OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “International
> Journal Of Industrial Engineering Computations”) OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE,
> “Neurocomputing”) OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “Advances In Production Engineering
> And Management”) OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “Flexible Services And Manufacturing
> Journal”) OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “IEEE Access”) OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE,
> “IEEE Computational Intelligence Magazine”) OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE,
> “IEEE Systems Journal”) OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “IEEE Transactions On Systems
> Man And Cybernetics Part C Applications And Reviews”) OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE,
> “Informs Journal On Computing”) OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “International Journal Of
> Bio Inspired Computation”) OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “International Journal Of Geographical
> Information Science”) OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “International Journal Of
> Shipping And Transport Logistics”) OR LIMIT-TO (EXACTSRCTITLE, “International Journal
> Of Sustainable Transportation”))

Answer (score 0):

I think one problem might be the missing ")" at the end. There should be three ), as you also start with 3.